# If P is not a reference type: If A is a reference type, the ref-qualifier of A’s type are ignored for type deduction

Tags: c++11, template-argument-deduction

I'm learning template argument deduction stuff,I have read <**14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call**>(C++11 draft) many times and I think that it missed a rule: 

If P is not a reference type: If A is a reference type, the ref-qualifier of A’s type are ignored for type deduction.

---

It must be my fault, but I dont know where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is the type of the function argument. A function argument is an expression, and expressions never have reference type. Suppose you have `int i;`, `int &r = i;`. Both the expression `i` and the expression `r` just have type `int`, and are lvalues. Neither has type `int &`. There are a few situations where a name is used other than as an expression (`decltype` has special exceptions for specific syntactic constructs, where they aren't treated as expressions), and in that case, the distinction matters, but using an object as a function argument is not one of them.